# Is a job in the hentai industry widely frowned upon in Japan?

Tags: anime-production, anime-industry

*[The Anime Man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Anime_Man)* has some interviews with people working in the anime industry. In [the one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n5sr-xdN13I&ab_channel=TheAnimeMan) with a creator of *Redo of Healer* and [the one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LBcJ59i-lcY&ab_channel=TheAnimeMan) with a Ǝ voice actress, the interviewees wear masks, while in [the one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tm0U9G4dj60&ab_channel=TheAnimeMan) with a normal innocent anime voice actress, the interviewee does not wear any mask. It seems that the 2 interviewees working in the hentai industry do not want others to know that.

Besides, there's also a similar phenomenon in *Kakushigoto*, where the father doesn't want her daughter to know that he's an eromanga sensei. Here's the [synopsis](https://myanimelist.net/anime/40716/Kakushigoto?q=kakushigoto&cat=anime#:%7E:text=Kakushi%20Gotou%20is,to%20his%20workplace.) from *MyAnimeList*.

> Kakushi Gotou is a somewhat popular manga artist whose works are known for inappropriate content. Because of this raunchiness, when his daughter Hime was born, he vowed to keep his profession hidden from her, believing that she will be disillusioned if she finds out.
>
> This paranoia-induced belief leads Kakushi into hectic situations. Despite being a single father, he does his best and often resorts to extreme ends just to protect his secret, such as guising as a salaryman every day or holding emergency drills in case Hime somehow finds her way to his workplace.

These materials make me wonder whether a job in the hentai industry is widely frowned upon in Japan.

Comment: Note that *Redo of Healer* is not hentai despite the content, and Tamiyasu Tomoe is using [her Vtuber persona](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC7yqc24BjJwi3PoqhXrx6og) despite her real-life photos being everywhere on the internet. Hiding the appearance for privacy reasons seems common in Japan, even for non-hentai works like [Tokyo Ghoul's Ishida Sui](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/39921/2516).

Comment: @AkiTanaka Redo of Healer lies at the borderline. You probably can find it in *hanime*. Tamiyasu Tomoe using avatar actually adds to the evidence that people in hentai industry don't want others to know the truth.

Comment: I guess that's one of the problems with the Westernized term "hentai", since in Japan, the light novel and manga of *Redo of Healer* are sold in non-adult (18+) sections, and it's also broadcasted on TV...

Comment: @AkiTanaka In general privacy is a big thing in Japan I heard? Like Tsugumi Ohba for Death Note and Negi Haruba for TQQ - they use pen names for anonymity and stuff?

Comment: To add to this, I know that a lot of Japanese VAs use pseudonyms when they appear in hentai.

Comment: @F1Krazy  Then, why don't seiyuu in innocent anime, say, Hanazawa and Atsumi, use pseudonyms? That boils down to people's opinion of that industry.

Comment: I know next to nothing about voice actresses, but just in general hentai industry is generally frowned upon for obvious reason. In particular there is discussion about banning pedophile manga/anime (legally). But why they use pseudonyms  or cover faces seems to depend on person. ([this](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1165076561) seems relevant, not seeable from Europe).

Comment: Hentai seiyuus do use aliases: https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/36207/why-do-seiyuu-famous-for-doing-eroge-still-use-alias/66105 and the reasons are pretty obvious. It's not that the business is frowned upon - there is a reason it is still going, but they tend to hide their faces because of the mentioned reasons. Again, it is their choice to hide their faces or not.